# Audiorecorder on matlab for Macintosh

Tags: macos, matlab, avaudiorecorder

Most functions for audiorecorder are only supported for the windows version. I have a 4-microphone array and i want to use each one separately. But i cannot specify the deviceID as it is not supported in Mac. It just uses the default device. It displays the following warning:

```
Warning: DeviceID parameter can only be set on Windows
```

IS there any option to do this?

Comment: If you have access to the Data Acquisition Toolbox, you could try the [analoginput](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/daq/ref/analoginput.html) function

Comment: I don't think the DAT is supported in the Mac version. Besides, there are only a couple of hardware supported by it - National Instruments, Mcc. I am using RME Fireface UFX.

Comment: sorry I didn't know that.. As a last option, maybe you can use a virtualization software to run Windows inside you Mac (VirtualBox is free and cross-platform)

Comment: If there is no other option i will try a Windows PC, but even so, there still could be hardware compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on similar problem: want to record from 2 microphones.

First of all: on Mac OS X, Matlab versions earlier than r2011a don't have multi input device support. So you must upgrade to r2011a. 
I've found in Matlab's r2011a release notes (http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/rn.pdf page 18)

> **audioplayer and audiorecorder Support Device** Selection on All
>   Platforms audioplayer and audiorecorder now allow you to specify the
>   input or output device on all supported platforms. In previous
>   releases, you could only specify devices on Microsoft Windows systems.

I'm testing it now, but it seems not to work properly (Built-in Input can't handle 44100Hz, 16bit, 1 channel recording) :-/

Upgrade to r2011a and we will try to solve this problem together.

*Upadte****
Here is what I did:
List all audio devices:

```
>> audiodevinfo

ans = 

     input: [1x2 struct]
    output: [1x1 struct]
```

List each input device:

```
>> audiodevinfo(1,0)

ans =

Built-in Microphone (Core Audio)

>> audiodevinfo(1,1)

ans =

Built-in Input (Core Audio)
```

Test desirable device (for me it was jack-plugged microphone):

```
>> audiodevinfo(1,1, 44100, 16, 1)

ans =

     1
```

function returned 1, so device IS ABLE to record 44100Hz,16bit,1channel audio signal.

Create audiorecorder object connected to desirable device:

> > r = audiorecorder(44100,16,1,1);

Record audio using **recordblocking** function (I don't need to record asynchronously and prefer recordblocking istead of record function, because I can see when recording process is finished).

Play it.

> > play(r);

Everything work's fine for me:)

Comment: I'm using an external interface (RME) so there might still be the issue of support. One thing i've noticed is that if i enable all the microphones, it displays as a single input device and not 4 different ones, in system preferences. I want to be able to record from all devices simultaneously and process the individual signals so upgrading the version may not be useful if the devices are not being distinguished or if only one device can be used at a time.